# Heroku run rake db:migrate command error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I created rails app follow this guid https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started. But when I run `Heroku run rake db:migrate` command return error : `Error:       Permission denied - connect(2) (Errno::EACCES)`

**UPDATED**
migration

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :tilte
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDTE 2**
heroku config

```
=== powerful-eyrie-5396 Config Vars                                                                                                                                                               
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://bqfsdarajfpdlk:4nU5FON87juyFwSdaX7Sr3Aicl@ec2-54-225-89-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d65593ob81m9g8                                                  
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL: postgres://bqfsdarajfpdlk:4nU5FON87juyFwSdaX7Sr3Aicl@ec2-54-225-89-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d65593ob81m9g8
```

**UPDATE 3** heroku command backtrace

```
Error:       Permission denied - connect(2) (Errno::EACCES)                                                                                                           
Backtrace:   /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `initialize'           
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `open'                 
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `block in start'       
             /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/ruby/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'                                                                                           
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'                
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:132:in `rendezvous_session'        
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:119:in `run_attached'              
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:24:in `index'                      
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'                           
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'                              
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/gems/heroku-2.39.4/bin/heroku:17:in `<top (required)>'                          
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/bin/heroku:23:in `load'                                                         
             /var/lib/stickshift/51bef7595973caa43f000531/app-root/data/lib/ruby/gems/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was resolved this command:

```
heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your database first

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

then

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: First command was successful. But second returned `error: Permission denied - connect(2) (Errno::EACCES)`

Comment: Could I see your migrations?

Comment: Ok, the migration source doesn't show anything special. Could you provide an output of `heroku config` command? I am interested in the `DATABASE_URL` string. Hope it isn't a secret.